# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable, don't know why this is happening

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def rectangleArea(l):
    lt = list(l[0])
    l = lt[:3:2]
    l.sort()
    x = l[1] - l[0]
    l = lt[1:4:2]
    l.sort()
    y = l[1] - l[0]
    area = x * y
    return area
l = [(30, 60, 60, 30), (50, 10, 10, 50)]
for i in range(2):
    print("Rectangle")
    la = l[i]
    print(la)
    area = rectangleArea(la)
    print(area)
```

Sorry for my bad english.
As you can see, tuples are in list 'l' and I don't want to edit this.
When I ran it without for loop, it worked well.
And with for loop, "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" appears.
The error message looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/MP09/help.py", line 19, in <module>
    area = rectangleArea(la)
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/MP09/help.py", line 3, in rectangleArea
    lt = list(l1[0])
```

I searched about it, and my situation isn't like the other.
I guess this is related with **la = l[i]** but i'm not sure.
What's wrong with this code. Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lt = list(l[0])` replace this with `lt = list(l)` in your code.

Your code picks rectangle sides one by one and passes into the function. Now inside the function, you just need to convert the tuple into a list but what you are doing is selecting the first element in it.

Comment: Wow it worked! Thanks! But can you tell me what was the problem?

Comment: Updated the answer. You can have a look.

Comment: Oh i got it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I was just about to answer this and saw that somebody else has, the problem is that list() returns a list from a tuple, string, list, or empty list.. you are passing a number into it in the function.. so..

```
lt = list(l[0])
    l = lt[:3:2]
    l.sort()
```

if you passed (30,60,60,30) into this rectangleArea function, you passed that tuple as l, then you asked for l[0] which is 30.. you can only pass a string, tuple, list, or empty list into the python list() function.. so this number is not iterable.. if it were a string, you would then in the next line be looking for an index 3 and 2 when '30' would only have 0 and 1 indexes.. but you aren't getting to that point.

[more info on list()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/list)

I hope this was helpful!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. :)